# If there exists an ε>0 such that for any δ>0 there are x1,x2∈(a−δ,a+δ) where |f(x1)−f(x2)| $\geq $ε, then f is discontinuous at a.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity

I want to prove the following theorem about a real-valued function $f$ defined on any interval and an arbitrary element $a$ in its domain:

> If there exists an $\varepsilon \gt 0$ such that for any $\delta \gt 0$ there are $x_1,x_2 \in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$ where $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\geq \varepsilon$, then $f$ is discontinuous at $a$.

I need this claim for another proof I am working on and just want to make sure that I did not overlook anything.

---

Suppose there is an $\varepsilon \gt 0$ such that for any $\delta \gt 0$, we can always find an $x_1,x_2 \in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$ that satisfies: $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\geq \varepsilon$. To show that $f$ is discontinuous at $a$, we need to show that there exists an $\eta \gt 0$ such that for any $\lambda \gt 0$ there is a $z\in(a-\lambda,a+\lambda)$ such that $|f(z)-f(a)|  \geq \eta$...or, equivalently: $f(z) \geq f(a) +\eta$ **or** $f(z) \leq f(a)-\eta$.

Suppose we let $\eta \lt \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Consider any arbitrary $\lambda \gt 0$. By assumption, there exist an $x_1,x_2 \in (a-\lambda,a+\lambda)$ such that $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)| \geq \varepsilon$. If either $f(x_1)=f(a)$ or $f(x_2)=f(a)$, then we are done by letting $z=x_2$ or $z=x_1$, respectively. So assume that $f(x_1) \neq f(a)$ and $f(x_2) \neq f(a)$.

There are two relevant cases to consider: $f(x_2) \in \left(f(a)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2},f(a)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \right) \setminus \{a\}$ and  $f(x_2) \in \left[f(a)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2},\infty \right) \cup  \left(-\infty, f(a)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2},-\infty \right] $. In the latter case, we see that we can just let $z = x_2$, and we are done.

So let $f(x_2) \in \left(f(a)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2},f(a)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \right) \setminus \{a\}$. Because $|f(x_1) - f(x_2)|\geq \varepsilon$, we must have that either $f(x_1) \geq f(x_2)+\varepsilon$ or $f(x_1) \leq f(x_2)-\varepsilon$.

*Former Case*: $f(x_1) \geq f(x_2)+\varepsilon\quad (*_1)$

By assumption, we know that $\displaystyle f(a) -\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \lt f(x_2) \lt f(a)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, which implies that: $\displaystyle f(a) +\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \lt f(x_2)+\varepsilon \lt f(a)+\frac{3\varepsilon}{2}$. But by $(*_1)$, this would imply that:

$$f(x_1) \gt f(a)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$, which means that we can let $z=x_1$.

*Latter Case*: $f(x_1) \leq f(x_2)-\varepsilon \quad (*_2)$

By assumption, we know that $\displaystyle f(a) -\frac{\varepsilon}{2} \lt f(x_2) \lt f(a)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, which implies that: $\displaystyle f(a) -\frac{3\varepsilon}{2} \lt f(x_2)-\varepsilon \lt f(a)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. But by $(*_2)$, this would imply that:

$$f(x_1) \lt f(a)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$, which means that we can let $z=x_1$.

---

As a side note, one should see that our argument was indifferent to which side of $a$ that $x_1$ and $x_2$ came from. So if the antecedent of our theorem is changed to $x_1,x_2 \in (a-\delta,a]$...or changed to $x_1,x_2 \in(a,a+\delta]$...or changed to $x_1 \in (a-\delta,a]$ and $x_2 \in [a,a+\delta)$...the claim remains valid.

Comment: I think you’re significantly overthinking it. Discontinuous at $a$ means **not** continuous at $a$, what is the contrapositive of your continuity definition?

Comment: @adfriedman I am not quite sure I understand the point you are making. Could you please clarify? Why should the antecedent automatically imply that $f$ must be discontinuous at $a$?

Comment: What is your $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity?

Comment: So you are saying that "$f$ is continuous at $y$ means that":

$$\forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \exists \delta \gt 0 \forall x \in [a,b]: |x-y|\lt \delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| \lt \varepsilon\iff \forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \exists \delta \gt 0 \forall x \in [a,b]: |f(x)-f(y)| \geq \varepsilon \rightarrow |x-y|\geq \delta$$

Comment: sure, and do you see why the criteria you gave in the question violates that?

Comment: @adfriedman I do not think I see what you are suggesting. If you could offer some some details, I would appreciate it.

Comment: The definition of $f$ being continuous means: for every $\epsilon> 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ where SOMETHING HAPPENS.  You are told that there is one $\epsilon > 0$ where for every $\delta > 0$ that SOMETHING DOES ***NOT*** HAPPEN.  If something does NOT happen for *every* $\delta$ then there does *not* exist *any* $\delta$ where SOMETHING *DOES* HAPPEN.  Thus for one $\epsilon > 0$ there DOESN'T exist a $\delta > 0$ where SOMETHING HAPPENS.  Thus it is NOT true that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ where SOMETHING HAPPENS. So $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: @fleablood Maybe I am misreading your comments, but you are making it seem like $\forall x \in (a-\delta,a+\delta): |f(x)-f(a)| \lt \varepsilon$ is the negated version of $\exists x_1,x_2 \in (a-\delta, a+\delta): |f(x_1)-f(x_2)| \geq \varepsilon$. How can this be?

Comment: Note $\epsilon \le |f(x_1) - f(x_2)|\le |f(x_1) - f(a)| + |f(a)-f(x_2)|$.  So either $|f(x_1)-f(a)|\ge \frac \epsilon 2$ or $|f(x_2)-f(a)| \ge \frac \epsilon 2$.   So it is *not* the case that for all $x \in (a-\delta, a+\delta)$ that $|f(x)-f(a)|< \frac \epsilon 2$ because for *any* $\delta > 0$ there will always be an $x_1,x_2 \in (a-\delta, a+ \delta)$ where at least one of $x_1,x_2$ fail.

Comment: @fleablood ahhh. I guess all of my work amounts to an application of the triangle inequality theorem (as your argument is essentially the compressed version of my argument). Got it. Thank you.